# Give an example of a non-zero linear operator $T$ on a vector space $V$ such that $T^{2}=O$ but $ \operatorname{Ker} T \neq \operatorname{Im} T$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Give an example of a non-zero linear operator $T$ on a vector space $V$  such that $T^{2}=O$ but $ \operatorname{Ker} T \neq \operatorname{Im} T$.

Comment: Any T whose image is _contained_ in the kernel will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T(e_1)=T(e_2)=0, T(e_3)=e_1$ in a $3$-dimensional vector space.